# Custom rails config for every domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an option, which should be set only for users who enters rails application via "domain.com" domain

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_builder_session', 
:domain => 'domain.com'
```

How to write a condition?

I have tried `if request.domain == 'domain.com')`, but `request` is not defined in `/config/environments/development.rb` yet

Comment: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Comment: You can't do this in your environments file because it loads at the time of application starts.